# Not able to restrict the user to particular directory in unix

Tags: bash, unix, sftp

Below are the steps I performed:

I created group sftponly.

Added one user named sftpusers to that group.

Added Subsystem sftp internal-sftp to file /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Added this line to the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Match group sftponly 
      ChrootDirectory /home/sftpusers 
      X11Forwarding no 
      AllowTcpForwarding no 
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

But the user is not restricted to the path /home/sftpusers. It is able to access directories of other users in /home. Is it possible to restrict user to a particular directory and not able to access other user directories in /home or any other path in unix.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar configuration to yours.

[ssh_config(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)
says:

> note that key-
>        words are case-insensitive and arguments are case-sensitive

So the first line in your config needs to have an upper case G, like so:

```
Match Group sftponly
```